# Conditional require and define for debugging

Tags: racket

I want to turn debugging on and off in my code, so I'm trying to do something like this at the top of my module...

```
(define DEBUGGING #f)
(if DEBUGGING
    (require unstable/debug)
    (define (debug x) void))
```

However I can't `require` or `define` inside a conditional. I've had a quick look at `dynamic-require` but can't figure out how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uselpa's answer has the correct idea. Here's an alternative implementation of the same idea using `syntax-case`, which is (IMHO) more readable, with slightly better error checking (if extraneous subforms are passed, for example):

```
(define-syntax (if-debug stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((_ debug-expr non-debug-expr)
     (if DEBUGGING
         #'debug-expr
         #'non-debug-expr))))
```

Answer (score 3):

First define `DEBUGGING` as a variable to be used at *expansion time*, not run time:

```scm
(define-for-syntax DEBUGGING #f)
```

then create a macro such as

```scm
(define-syntax (if-debug stx)
  (let ((dat (syntax->datum stx)))
    (if DEBUGGING
        (datum->syntax stx (cadr dat))
        (datum->syntax stx (caddr dat)))))
```

and finally use as

```scm
(if-debug
   (require unstable/debug)
   (define (debug x) void))
```

Comment: Why do I get a ?: literal data is not allowed;
 no #%datum syntax transformer is bound in the transformer environment in: #f error for #f at first line?

Comment: Hmm for reasons alien to me, it works if I use lang racket instead of lang racket/base + require all the missing modules listed in the reference

Answer (score 0):

I like uselpa's answer, especially with Chris' refinement. I've used that sort of approach myself. But honestly: What I would do these days is simply supply both expressions and un-comment the alternative I want at the time:

```
;; (require unstable/debug)
(define (debug x) (void))
```

or:

```
(require unstable/debug)
;; (define (debug x) (void))
```

Admittedly this "macro via commenting" isn't a runtime choice -- but neither are the macro answers.

Although low tech, this does have the advantage of being just 2 lines of clear, obvious code.

I'd particularly prefer this if it's going to get copied into multiple sources files.

I'd probably prefer this even if it goes in one file that `provide`s `debug` and is `require`d by many others.

Comment: Interesting... that's the approach I'm using while I wait for the answer to this question :)

Comment: Well, either you edit the file to alternate `#t` and `#f`, or, to alternate which line is commented. Practically, they seem equivalent to me -- except a dozen lines of code vs. 2 to do the same thing. _shrug_

Comment: One difference: there are other things I want to toggle when debugging, like adding trace to a few methods and I think these have to go at the end of the source file.

Comment: Yes, that would start to nudge me back to the other approach.

Comment: Although a bit late, I felt obliged to comment. I think the macro answers is indeed "runtime" choice as opposed to what you claim, Greg. I'll share what I tried with the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I used the answers successfully in a simple script and would like to share the addition. You can actually use any form instead of a boolean DEBUG, effectively not needing to change the code. I didn't want to change/comment-out multiple lines on multiple scripts everytime, and this solution lets me run on drracket and use repl or run from shell (by adding a first arg to the command or not):

```
; @echo off
; "C:\Program Files\Racket\racket.exe" "%~f0" %*
; exit /b
#lang racket
(define-for-syntax args (current-command-line-arguments))
(define-for-syntax PROTOTYPING (or
                            (= (vector-length args) 0)
                            (equal? (vector-ref args 0) "local")))

(define-syntax (if-prototyping stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((_ debug-expr non-debug-expr)
     (if PROTOTYPING
         #'debug-expr
         #'non-debug-expr))))

(if-prototyping
   (require (file "C:/file1.rkt"))
            (file "C:/util1.rkt""))
   (require (file "C:/file2.rkt"))
            (file "C:/util2.rkt")))
```